# My Data is not being Saved in my database correctly

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, schema, mern

When i save my data to the database within an array it does not work but when i just send a single object it is stored correctly. Maybe my schema is incorrect?

This is my SChema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  colorC: String,
  sizeC: String,
  date: Date,
  title: String,
  transactionID: Number,
  count: Number
});

const CartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  products: [ProductSchema]
});

const Cart = mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema);

module.exports = {
  cartModel: mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema),
  productModel: mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
};
this is my post request

 const express = require('express');
const Cart = require('../models/Cart');
const models = require('../models/Cart');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { colorC, sizeC, date, title, transactionID, count } = req.body;
  try {
    const newProduct = new models.productModel({
      colorC,
      sizeC,
      date,
      title,
      transactionID,
      count
    });
    const newPurchase = new models.cartModel({
      products: [newProduct.toJSON()]
    });

      await newProduct.save();
      await newPurchase.save()
      const products = newProduct;
    const purchase =  newPurchase + products;

    res.json(purchase);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

When i send the data as an array containing two objects none of the data shows up for instance this is supposed to show the object i input. When i send this the server does not save any products in the array.

```
[{

"colorC": null,
"count": 1,
"date": "Mon Jul 29 2019 02:08:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
"sizeC": "Small",
"title": "COMME DES GARCONS TEE",
"transactionID": 1564380487732

},{

"colorC": null,
"count": 1,
"date": "Mon Jul 29 2019 02:08:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
"sizeC": "Small",
"title": "COMME DES GARCONS TEE",
"transactionID": 1564380487732

}]
```

This is the data saved in the Database

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5d42ab9f4ec81021f0136e95"},
    "products":[{"_id":{"$oid":"5d42ab9f4ec81021f0136e94"}}]
    ,"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
    }
```

Comment: Cause toJson is not what you think, it just return the attributes not the model data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change my post method

```
const express = require("express");
const models = require("../models/Cart");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const newPurchase = new models.cartModel({
    products: req.body.map(element => {
      const { colorC, sizeC, date, title, transactionID, count } = element;
      return { colorC, sizeC, date, title, transactionID, count };
    })
  });

  newPurchase
    .save()
    .then(purchase => res.json(purchase))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

toJson function doesn't return the model data.

Comment: Okay but even if I remove tojson I still don’t get my data stored the way I want it unfortunately

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to store in 2 places product first

Comment: Yes that doesn’t make sense I was advised to do this on another question wouldn’t new Purchase save new product as well?

Comment: Yes if you save the model cart then  you have all the products there no need for another model for products or maybe they tried to tell you to only store the id of the product in Cart and the product itself in product

Comment: Wait so I don’t need another model for products?

Comment: As this helps with saving multiple models why isnt my data saving correctly?

Comment: You have 2 choices either 1 model Cart and then you store the products in the field products inside Cart or 2 model and then the product is stored in its own model and then the Id is used in the field products inside cart.

Comment: So store the products Schema inside of cart?

Comment: On mobile cant get the formatting right here is a link https://rextester.com/edit/CNRK91900 , this is the choice 1